# Expanded Sorting of dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have formed a result set like the below from 6 different tables. I got 6 different dates.

[image]

I have to derive a result set like the below.

[image]

I tried with the below code.

```
DECLARE @Input TABLE (
    year INT
    ,fmy CHAR(2)
    ,model CHAR(6)
    ,d1 DATE
    ,d2 DATE
    ,d3 DATE
    ,d4 DATE
    ,d5 DATE
    ,d6 DATE
    )
DECLARE @FinalResult TABLE (
    year INT
    ,fmy CHAR(2)
    ,model CHAR(6)
    ,d1 DATE
    ,d2 DATE
    ,d3 DATE
    ,d4 DATE
    ,d5 DATE
    ,d6 DATE
    )
DECLARE @year INT
    ,@fmy CHAR(2)
    ,@model CHAR(6)
    ,@d1 DATE
    ,@d2 DATE
    ,@d3 DATE
    ,@d4 DATE
    ,@d5 DATE
    ,@d6 DATE

INSERT INTO @Input
SELECT *
FROM (
    VALUES (
        2018
        ,'DD'
        ,'FCRAC2'
        ,'1/1/2018'
        ,'1/1/2018'
        ,'1/1/2018'
        ,'1/1/2018'
        ,'1/1/2018'
        ,'1/1/2018'
        )
        ,
        (
        2018
        ,'DD'
        ,'FCRAC2'
        ,'07/10/2018'
        ,NULL
        ,'01/08/2019'
        ,'03/01/2018'
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        )
        ,(
        2018
        ,'DD'
        ,'FCRAC2'
        ,'09/05/2018'
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,'07/03/2018'
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        )
        ,(
         2018
        ,'DD'
        ,'FCRAC2'
        ,'01/08/2019'
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,'01/08/2019'
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        )
        --,(
        --2018
        --,'DD'
        --,'FCRAC2'
        --,'9/5/2018'
        --,NULL
        --,NULL
        --,NULL
        --,NULL
        --,NULL
        --)
    ) T(year, fmy, model, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6)

DECLARE @datecount INT = 0
    ,@i INT = 1
    ,@outputdate DATE

--select *from (
--select distinct d1
--From @Input
--union 
--select distinct d2
--From @Input
--union 
--select distinct d3
--From @Input
--union 
--select distinct d4
--From @Input
--union 
--select distinct d5
--From @Input
--union 
--select distinct d6
--From @Input
--)T(dates)
--where dates is not null


DECLARE inputcursor CURSOR

FOR
SELECT *
FROM @Input

OPEN inputcursor

FETCH NEXT
FROM inputcursor
INTO @year
    ,@fmy
    ,@model
    ,@d1
    ,@d2
    ,@d3
    ,@d4
    ,@d5
    ,@d6

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @datecount = count(DISTINCT dates)
    FROM (
        VALUES (@d1)
            ,(@d2)
            ,(@d3)
            ,(@d4)
            ,(@d5)
            ,(@d6)
        ) T(Dates)
    WHERE dates IS NOT NULL

    WHILE (@i <= @datecount)
    BEGIN
            ;

        WITH cte
        AS (
            SELECT dates
                ,row_number() OVER (
                    ORDER BY dates
                    ) rn
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT dates
                FROM (
                    VALUES (@d1)
                        ,(@d2)
                        ,(@d3)
                        ,(@d4)
                        ,(@d5)
                        ,(@d6)
                    ) T(Dates)
                WHERE dates IS NOT NULL
                    --and id=@datecount
                ) d
            )
        SELECT @outputdate = dates
        FROM cte
        WHERE rn = @i           

        insert into @FinalResult 
        SELECT @year
            ,@fmy
            ,@model
            ,CASE 
                WHEN @d1 = @outputdate
                    THEN @d1
                ELSE NULL
                END
                ,CASE 
                WHEN @d2 = @outputdate
                    THEN @d2
                ELSE NULL
                END
                ,CASE 
                WHEN @d3 = @outputdate
                    THEN @d3
                ELSE NULL
                END
                ,CASE 
                WHEN @d4 = @outputdate
                    THEN @d4
                ELSE NULL
                END
                ,CASE 
                WHEN @d5 = @outputdate
                    THEN @d5
                ELSE NULL
                END
                ,CASE 
                WHEN @d6 = @outputdate
                    THEN @d6
                ELSE NULL
                END

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    SET @i = 1

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM inputcursor
    INTO @year
        ,@fmy
        ,@model
        ,@d1
        ,@d2
        ,@d3
        ,@d4
        ,@d5
        ,@d6
END

CLOSE inputcursor

DEALLOCATE inputcursor

select *from @Input

select * from @FinalResult
```

I have given input data in the form of SQL in my code itself.

It is working for this result set but the same code is not working for the input below.

[image]

I am trying to find any other way to do it without using loops. I have thousand plus models with each model has 10 to 20 records. I have given a sample record set for one model.

The following things should be considered for the final result set.

1. If all the 6 dates are same for a particular model then we can show it in single row.
2. Dates should be in sorted order. lets say for row number 2 we have three dates. so we should display it in three rows under its corresponding column consider that the final complete result set would be in a sorted manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to get the list of distinct dates from your table, and perform a `LEFT JOIN` back to the table. Then you can use a `CASE` expression to only show the date when it's the same value as that row:

```
DECLARE @Input table (year int,
                      fmy char(2),
                      model char(6),
                      d1 date,
                      d2 date,
                      d3 date,
                      d4 date,
                      d5 date,
                      d6 date);

INSERT INTO @Input
SELECT T.year,
       T.fmy,
       T.model,
       CONVERT(date,T.d1,101),
       CONVERT(date,T.d2,101),
       CONVERT(date,T.d3,101),
       CONVERT(date,T.d4,101),
       CONVERT(date,T.d5,101),
       CONVERT(date,T.d6,101)
FROM (VALUES (2018, 'DD', 'FCRAC1', '1/1/2017', '1/1/2017', '1/1/2017', '1/1/2017', '1/1/2017', '1/1/2017'),
             (2018, 'DD', 'FCRAC1', '1/8/2018', '12/31/2017', NULL, '1/8/2018', NULL, NULL),
             (2018, 'DD', 'FCRAC1', '5/24/2018', NULL, NULL, '3/1/2018', NULL, NULL),
             (2018, 'DD', 'FCRAC1', '7/3/2018', NULL, NULL, '7/3/2018', NULL, NULL),
             (2018, 'DD', 'FCRAC1', '9/5/2018', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)) AS T (year, fmy, model, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6);

WITH Dates AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT D
    FROM @Input
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(d1),(d2),(d3),(d4),(d5),(d6)) V(D))
SELECT I.[year],
       I.fmy,
       I.model,
       CASE D.D WHEN I.d1 THEN I.d1 END AS d1,
       CASE D.D WHEN I.d2 THEN I.d2 END AS d2,
       CASE D.D WHEN I.d3 THEN I.d3 END AS d3,
       CASE D.D WHEN I.d4 THEN I.d4 END AS d4,
       CASE D.D WHEN I.d5 THEN I.d5 END AS d5,
       CASE D.D WHEN I.d6 THEN I.d6 END AS d6
FROM Dates D
     LEFT JOIN @Input I ON D.D IN (I.D1,I.D2,I.D3,I.D4,I.D5,I.D6)
WHERE D.D != '20180905' --As this wasn't in your expected results, assumed filter out
ORDER BY D.D;
```

*Note: This is unlikely to be performant with a large data set.*

Comment: Excellent Thank you for your solution. It works well in this data set. I have to check my complete data set now. Will it create any performance impact.

Comment: This solution is not working for another scenario. I have updated my question with another input data set. Here I am not getting the expected result with this new input data set. I am hitting my heads why it was not working as expected.

Comment: This answer was given over a month ago @StackUser . If you have a new question you should ask a new question, not changing an answered question.